# HBASE copy first few records from one table to another?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a table 'X" in . Hbase that has millions of records i need to create another table 'mini_x' which has only 100 records of 'X' how do i create one such ??

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create table "mini_x" in HBase then,

- **Either** you can Use HBase API with Java to get records from main table "X", Filter them and then put to another table.
  **OR** You can use Hadoop MapReduce Job to read one HBase table and put the selected records in another table(mini_x)